# CSS3 Translate3d parameters, distance to travel or grid location?

Tags: html, css

My understanding was that if I had, for example, `translate3d(10px,10px,0)`, this would simply move the object from it's current position to 10px up and 10px right. This is how [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function#translate3d()) explains it. However, when building an off-canvas menu, I have stumbled upon what seems to contract this.

I start by calling `translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)` to have my menu off the viewport (it's absolutely positioned to be out of the flow). Then, when I want to show it, I call `translate3d(0,0,0)` to bring it into the left of the view port. But from the original description of the parameters via MDN, `translate3d(0,0,0)` shouldn't move the element at all, so why is this working?

Comment: Because translate always refers to its original position, not from the last translated position. So applying translate -100% first and then translate 0 is like not translate it at all

Comment: @JonasGrumann he is saying it is translating though

Comment: Yes, because translate(0,0,0) is its original position without any translation applied, so it basically resets the -100% translation

Comment: @JonasGrumann thank you for the clarification, that makes perfect sense! I did not realize that the reference was always to the original spot on the grid, thank you!

Comment: so you're saying that since he invokes translate after screen load to do the -100% by later applying the translate at 0 it is going back to the original position?

Comment: @CayceK exactly, that's what I'm saying